# NullPointer when accessing toolbar with findviewbyid android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am using support.v7.widget.Toolbar, and it is not able to find the toolbar by R.id.xyzname findviewbyid. Both toolbar and toolbars return nil. So the code crashes with NullPointer at
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

The same application works fine when testing in a device with version 23; The code crashes with NullPointer when testing with a device with version 16.

Here is my activity

```
class classActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        mOpenHelper = new IncidentOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());


        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout   = (AppBarLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.app_toolbar, null);
        // [the above code helped me solve the issue]

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbars = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) appBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar);



        setSupportActionBar(toolbars);


        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
}
```

Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="session_management.LoginActivity">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>

<!--
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

-->

    <LinearLayout


  </Linear layout>





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is my dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile project('libraries:volley')
/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                */
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
compile project(':cloudendpoint')
```

}

here is my app_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for the last two days. Have searched SO and read the Google Docs associated as well. Any guidance or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand the down vote. Can you please explain why the down vote?

Comment: Finally solved it after inflating the toolbar.  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbars = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) layout1.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar); I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use v7 support toolbar to support lower devices. Like this

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar);
```

Comment: Thanks Faisi. Just stepped out of my laptop. Will test and get back to you.

Comment: I am still getting the same issues. I have updated my code and the question to include android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Please see above.

Comment: make sure your activity extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: the class already has AppCompatActivity. I have updated my question. The code works perfectly on a device that has Android version 23. It breaks on the device with Android version 16.